# MVC routing service which performs custom rolebased authorisation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC 4.0 project. In order to do the rolebased on authorisation on action methods I have implemented a solution of custom authorisation attribute solution already.But this solution is not accepted in review and I was told to create a service which handles the authorisation and routing.

Answer (score 0):

```
On the gloabl.asas.cs file you can add the below event and then do whatever you want to do

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (Features.UserValidationEnabled)
                    {
          if (!safeExtension && Security.CurrentUser.IsInRole("User"))
                            {
                                if (!AccountManager.CheckFlag(Security.CurrentUser, AccountManager.Capabilities.IsValidated))
                                {
                                    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith("~/Account", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Validate");
                                    }
                                }
        }
        }}
```